# How to draw Complicated shapes in html5 canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-canvas

I have a brain image like the one I attached below which I want to draw on canvas.
I see that it can be drawn by using many beizercurves or quadraticCurves.

My requirement is to draw the shape only by using html canvas or css, without svg, and without images.

Is there any easier way to draw them on canvas?
Are there any formulas like the formulas used to create sine waves,  that I can use to draw these curves.

Thanks in advance!!
[image]

Answer (score 1):

In general you would use a bezier curve to draw shapes like this.
To create a bezier curve with html5 canvas use the bezierCurveTo() function.
But it will still be very tedious to draw this kind of shape.